# Run/execute multiple procedures in Parallel - Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, parallel-processing, dbms-scheduler

I have an Activity table which is getting all the table events of the system. Events like new orders, insertion/deletion on all the system tables will be inserted into this table. So, the no of events/sec is really huge for Activity table.

Now, I want to process the incoming events based on the business logic depending on the table responsible for raising the event. Every table may have different procedure to do the processing.

I used the same link 
[Parallelizing calls in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530900/parallelizing-calls-in-pl-sql)

As a solution I have created multiple `dbms_scheduler` jobs which will be called at the same time. All these jobs (`JOB1, JOB2--- - -JOB10`) will have the same procedure (**`ProcForAll_Processing`**) as `JOB_ACTION` to achieve parallel processing.

```
begin
    dbms_scheduler.run_job('JOB1',false);
    dbms_scheduler.run_job('JOB2',false);
  end;
```

**`ProcForAll_Processing`**: This procedure in turn will call 6 other procedures
`Proc1,proc2,proc3 --- -- - -- - Proc6` in sequential manner. I want to achieve parallel processing for these as well.

P.S: We can’t create further jobs to achieve parallel processing in **`ProcForAll_Processing`** proc as it may lead to consume further resources and also DBA is not agreeing for creating further jobs. Also, I can't use 
**`dbms_parallel_execute`** for parallel processing.

Please help me as I am really stuck to get it done

Comment: It'd be better to move all the multithreading to some other place in the application (frontend, middle-tier). Nearly all OOP languages support multithreading.

Comment: using OOP language is not possible here as all the work done in the database only. Even output is being sent via the web service call at DB level.

Comment: In that case, you can try adapting Producer-Consumer design pattern with some limited size of Queue and number of thread-like jobs, not to create too much load on your database.

Comment: I am using thread like jobs but the no. of producers events is so large that I can't create large no of jobs for the consumers. I thought to create 10 jobs initially, but in that case the no of events for 1 job is large so I want to achieve parallel process inside the job level as well, but I can't create jobs further in the job action procedure.

Comment: Well. The easiest option seems to be writing some simple multithreading application in Java/C# using JDBC. It shouldn't be that hard even if you're a back-end developer. Here you got some simple examples of Consumer-Producer implementations http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/thread_procon.htm, https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java-multithreading/java-multithreading-producer-consumer-blockingqueue-part-7.html plus some JDBC tutorials http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/index.htm, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible in general case without jobs, and it will make multiple sessions for this. There is no such thing as multithreading `PL\SQL` with a few exceptions. One of them is **parallel execution of sql** statements [1]. So there are some attempts to **abuse** this stuff for parallel execution of PL\SQL code, for example try to look here [2].

But as i've said it's **abuse** IMHO.

Reference:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/usingpe.htm
2. http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/parallel-plsql-launcher.html

Comment: If your processing logic is row by row, you might want to consider converting it to use a set based algorithm; that then lends itself to parallel execution. Running multiple threads of row by row will only scale so far.

Comment: I just quickly reviewed Reference #2 above. I think the Author said it himself. Quote: What this was really telling me is that I didn't fully understand PQ.

Comment: @BobC but eventually he managed to get parallel execution, maybe without deep understanding of guts under the hood.

Comment: @IlyaMaskov. His work leaves a lot to be desired. There are a few missteps, misconceptions and misunderstandings. So would you really want to base you work on this? That's one of the problem with the internet; everything is assumed to be good and true.

Comment: @BobC `His work leaves a lot to be desired` — exactly. Nobody said that it's good and appropriate for real use. Have you seen the bold word **abuse** in my text? It's just a survey of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Get a new DBA.  Or even better, cut them out of any decision making processes.  A DBA should not review your code and should not tell you to not create jobs, unless there is a good, specific reason.

Using DBMS_SCHEDULER to run things in parallel is by far the easiest and most common way to achieve this result.  *Of course* it's going to consume more resources, that's what parallelism will inevitably do.

Another, poorer option, is to use parallel pipelined table functions.  It's an advanced PL/SQL feature that can't be easily explained in a simple example.  The best I can do is refer you to [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS01210).

Comment: Thank You Jon, you are a champ! Now, I can put both the options  DBMS_SCHEDULER and parallel pipelined table functions

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE (since RDBMS 11).

https://blogs.oracle.com/warehousebuilder/entry/parallel_processing_in_plsql

https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2