# How to execute a stored procedure in a different session in same time in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, session, stored-procedures, plsql

Is there anyway possible in PL/SQL to invoke multiple sessions and run a procedure in the multiple sessions simultaneously.

I want to use this in a real time applications where there are 250 users logging into the application. The users are connected to Oracle through a client tool. (Power Builder is the Front End Tool)

For example, if an user calls an stored procedure, that stored procedure has to be run for 10 times with different parameter values.
I don't want to run this sequentially one after another for 10 times in the same session because it may take long time.
I am looking for a way where I can run the stored procedure in 10 different sessions simultaneously.

I thought about placing 10 jobs using DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT but because of
the heavy job load ( 250 users * 10 = 2500 jobs may be scheduled in the Job scheduler at the same time and so on) our DBA group is looking for some other better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run/execute multiple procedures in Paralel oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947855/run-execute-multiple-procedures-in-paralel-oracle)

Comment: Since you say you have many users that want to run this procedure, you should check first if your database can handle that many parallel executions. Roughly one stored procedure per core running simultaneously (perhaps a little more) is the best you will get. What is the waiting time if you have ONE concurrent user executing the stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid posting several Oracle jobs, you could try using William Robertson **[Parallel PL/SQL launcher](http://williamrobertson.net/documents/parallel-plsql-launcher.html)**.

> if you create a table "`PQ_DRIVER`" with 4 partitions and a parallel degree of 4, with one row in each partition, and you execute a query along the lines of "`SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(pq,4) */ thread_id FROM pq_driver pq`", that should persuade the PQ controller to set four PQ slave processes to work on it (one per partition). And if you pass that query as a cursor parameter to a parallel-enabled pipelined function, then shouldn't that create a situation where each each row is processed by a separate PQ slave process? So here is a way to use (alright, hack) the PQ engine so that it processes arbitrary PL/SQL procedure calls in parallel.

The idea is to create a function using **`PARALLEL_ENABLE`** and **`PIPELINED`** features:

```
   function pq_submit
    ( p_job_list  varchar2_tt
    , p_pq_refcur rc_pq_driver )
    return varchar2_tt
    parallel_enable(partition p_pq_refcur by any)
    pipelined
 is
 ...
 loop
   execute_command(your_proc);
 end loop;
```

Function `execute_command` uses **`autonomous_transaction`**.

It looks like this:

```
procedure execute_command
  ( p_what log_times.what%type )
is
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  execute immediate p_what;
  commit;
end execute_command;
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to creating `JOB`s you may use the [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2) [package](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_parallel_ex.htm#ARPLS233).

Here some hits:

Use `create_chunks_by_sql` with `by_rowid  => FALSE`, i.e. using ID and create exact the same number of chunks as the required execution of the stored procedure.

In `run_task` set the `parallel_level` to the required degree of parallelism. This is the same number as above or lower if you need o throttle the parallelism.

Pass the call of the
procedure as the parameter `sql_stmt` e.g.

```
BEGIN
  test_proc(:start_id,:end_id);
END;
```

Optionally as you see it is possible to pass the chunk number to the procedure, so you may use it as a `threadId`.

Here a complete example

**Create task and 3 chunks**

```
DECLARE
  l_stmt CLOB;
BEGIN
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_task (task_name => 'parallel PL/SQL');

  l_stmt := 'SELECT rownum, rownum FROM dual connect by level <= 3';

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_chunks_by_sql(task_name => 'parallel PL/SQL',
                                             sql_stmt  => l_stmt,
                                             by_rowid  => FALSE);
END;
/
```

**Run the task with DOP = 3**

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  l_sql_stmt := 'BEGIN
                   test_proc(:start_id,:end_id);
                END;';   

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task(task_name      => 'parallel PL/SQL',
                                 sql_stmt       => l_sql_stmt,
                                 language_flag  => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
                                 parallel_level => 3);
END;
/
```

**Remove the Task**

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.drop_task('parallel PL/SQL');
END;
/
```